# My computer is working but my screen is black after accidentally pulling out the monitor wire

Tags: display, blank-screen

I accidentally pulled out the monitor wire when I wanted to move my computer, but when I plugged it in again, the monitor showed a black screen when the computer turned on.

I know the monitor is safe because the lamp of the monitor is on and none of the computer components are burnt because I do not smell burnt and the monitor wire is firmly in place because I have tried it many times.

Where do you think my problem is?

[image: Monitor connection]

Comment: Computers often have multiple graphics ports of the same type. May you plugged in the cable into the wrong one? Monitors allow to switch between multiple input sources. May be accidentally it was switched to an unused input port and stays there ignoring the other port connected to your PC.

Comment: Is the DVI to VGA adapter connected directly to your graphics card or is there some cable going into your case?

Comment: Based on the posted picture, it doesn’t seem like the video card in the PC is actually connected to the case. It just seems to be dangling there. But my guess is the way you _don’t_ have the card secured caused something on the video card to crack. Or heck, the video card itself was jostled out of the slot it was connected to on the motherboard. Regardless, this is a fairly (and I hate to say this) sloppy setup. Power down the PC, disconnect the video cable, open the case up, reseat the video card and then reconnect the video cable and start again.

Answer (score 3):

it's difficult to determine precisely from the image, but monitor connections are usually attached to a slot cover which is attached to the graphics adapter card. I do not see a slot cover and the angle of the cable indicates that the connection to the card is probably damaged/cracked/broken from the graphics adapter.